# WURFL and Zend Page Caching

Tags: zend-framework, wurfl, zend-cache

I seem to have a chicken/egg situation that I cannot resolve.  I'm using WURFL to sniff mobile clients for my site and varying content based it.  This happens in a Controller_Plugin.

I'm looking at adding page caching, but as far as I know, that can only be initiated in the bootstrap.  In order to cache pages correctly, I need to know if the page is mobile or not, but I don't have that data until later on down the road, so to speak...

Maybe someone who understands the Zend Application workflow would know where I could sneak in the page caching after getting the user agent info, or is it too late at that point?

Comment: Are you wanting to cache pages differently for mobile devices? Or only cache for mobile devices?

Comment: I need to cache the pages different for mobile, yes.  I'm building page cache keys based off of URI, QUERY_STRING and other _SERVER vars.  I can save IS_MOBILE in the _SERVER array, but it is after the bootstrap...

Comment: First at all I would prefer to use an proxy cache like varnish. For ``Zend\Cache\Frontend\Page`` your simply have to call the method ``start`` with a different id argument in both cases. this can be done on controller level after bootstrap.

Comment: @mabe.berlin yes, varnish is on my radar. I'm very interested on how to work with dynamic content with varnish and have been studying ESIs for a little while now. In the interim, I was able to solve this problem by moving the WURFL plugin into my bootstrap and my pagecache into a plugin; basically swapping the locations in the call stack.